# Как изменить при помощи скрипта значения другого скрипта *на другом объекте* unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем есть у меня объект со скриптом scr. Мне нужно при помощи скрипта sced изменить значение скрипта scr конкретно для указанного объекта со скриптом, а для всех остальных его не трогать.